# 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0] when converting raster stack to data frame using as.data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, raster, glm

I have created a stack of layers, and I am getting the following error when trying to convert a raster stack into a data frame. The same process for my training data has worked fine.

```
testStack <- stack(testD, landCover_dis, elevation, ndvi, plCurv, prCurv, roadsDist, slope, spi, tpi, tri, twi, waterDist, lithology_dis)
names(testStack) <- c("landslides", "landCover", "elevation", "ndvi", "plCurv", "prCurv", "roadsDist", "slope", "spi", "tpi", "tri", "twi", "waterDist", "lithology")
```

```
test.df <- as.data.frame(na.omit(testStack))
```

Error message is:

```
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

The problem arises when I apply the `ratify()` function to set a layer of the RasterStack as discrete. However, it is not a problem in my other `trainStack`, which I have done other manipulations with.

EDIT

Output from dput() with problematic raster layer (ratify() applied) is

```
'new("RasterLayer", file = new(".RasterFile", name = "file", 
    datanotation = "INT1U", byteorder = "little", nodatavalue = -Inf, 
    NAchanged = FALSE, nbands = 1L, bandorder = "BIL", offset = 0L, 
    toptobottom = TRUE, blockrows = c(rows = 16L), blockcols = c(cols = 256L), 
    driver = "gdal", open = FALSE), data = new(".SingleLayerData", 
    values = logical(0), offset = 0, gain = 1, inmemory = FALSE, 
    fromdisk = TRUE, isfactor = TRUE, attributes = list(structure(list(
        ID = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L))), haveminmax = TRUE, min = 1, max = 19, band = 1L, 
    unit = "", names = "lc_30__c"), legend = new(".RasterLegend", 
    type = character(0), values = logical(0), color = logical(0), 
    names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), title = character(0), 
    extent = new("Extent", xmin = 451086, xmax = 471666, ymin = 5600712, 
        ymax = 5617092), rotated = FALSE, rotation = new(".Rotation", 
        geotrans = numeric(0), transfun = function () 
        NULL), ncols = 686L, nrows = 546L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), 
    srs = "+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs", 
    history = list(), z = list())
'
```

Comment: Can you share an example of what the data looks like, ideally using `dput()`?

Comment: Just added the dput() output of the problematic raster layer to the description